# Navigate forwards and backwards in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, web, razor

I have 5 fields

Field 1 is a number field
Field 2-4 are letter fields

I want to be able to navigate from the number field to the first letter field with TAB and back again with SHIFT+TAB.
I want to be able to navigate forward from field 2 to field 4 not with TAB, but navigate back with SHIFT+TAB, for example from field 3 to field 2.
Navigating forward in the letter fields is done automatically, as soon as there are 4 letters in the text field it automatically jumps to the next field.

I am not getting any further, so far I have the following script code and the corresponding fields.
The automatic forward navigation works and the navigation with TAB is deactivated. Unfortunately, I can no longer navigate from the number field to the letter fields.
Navigating back does not work. As soon as I go back with SHIFT+Tab, it immediately jumps back into the field if there are 4 characters in the letter field.

What else am I missing or what have I implemented incorrectly?

```
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    $(".form-control").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 9) { 
            if (e.shiftKey) {                     
            } else {
                e.preventDefault(); 

                if (this.value.length === this.maxLength) {                        
                    $(this).parent().next().find('.form-control').focus();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $(".form-control").keyup(function () {
        if (this.value.length === this.maxLength) {
            var $next = $(this).parent().next().find('.form-control');
            if ($next.length)
                $next.focus();
            else
                $(this).blur();
        }
    });
</script>
```

}

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="col-form-label">@HtmlLocalizer["Number"]</label>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Number, new { oninput = "javascript: this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')", @class = "form-control"})                    
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
</div>           
            
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="LetterField1" maxlength="4" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="LetterField2" maxlength="4" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="LetterField3" maxlength="4" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="LetterField4" maxlength="4" />
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: tab/shift-tab should already be working... seems like you should remove the keydown function and you'd be good.  (it currently does nothing on shift anyway, and prevents default for key 9...)   Are you trying to prevent the normal tab behavior when there are less than 4 characters?

Comment: I have removed the keydown function. Now I can tab from the number field to field 2, but also to the other fields. This should not be the case for field 2-4. Tab behaviour should not be active for fields 2-4. SHIFT+TAB only works correctly if fields 2-4 are empty. As soon as 4 letters are included, it jumps back to the field it came from. This should not be the case. This is probably due to the automatic jump as soon as 4 letters are contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a demo to reproduce your project and it works as you said, Hope it can give you some help.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input class="form-control letter-field" asp-for="LetterField1" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input class="form-control letter-field" asp-for="LetterField2" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input class="form-control letter-field" asp-for="LetterField3" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input class="form-control letter-field" asp-for="LetterField4" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>

        $(".letter-field").keydown(function (e) {
           if (e.keyCode === 9) {
                
                if (e.shiftKey) {
                    
                }else{
                    e.preventDefault();
                }              
           }       
        });

        $(".letter-field").keyup(function (e) {
        if ( e.key === "Tab" || e.key === "Shift") {
           
       }else{
            if (this.value.length === this.maxLength) {
                if (e.shiftKey && e.key === "Tab") {

                } else if (!e.shiftKey) {
                    var $next = $(this).parent().next().find('.letter-field');
                    if ($next.length) {

                        $next.focus();
                    }
                    else
                        $(this).blur();
                }
            }
       }           
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have adopted it and unfortunately it doesn't quite work yet. If I now enter 4 characters in field 2, the cursor stays in field 2 and does not automatically jump to field 3. It only jumps to field 3 when you press any key. It should automatically jump to the next field after entering the fourth character. SHIFT-TAB works, but I can't adjust the value in fields 2-4 if I make a mistake. When I try to adjust one of the fields 2-4, it jumps to the next field.

Comment: Hi @Kojote, Check the answer i updated, It works as you excepted